# Get packet that's being routed

Tags: linux, routes, network-programming

I have a Linux box which is routing TCP/IP.  I would like to see the contents of the packets that are being routed.  I can do this with libpcap, but, I'm looking for a way which is simpler and better performance.

Is there any way to get a socket or any other type of interface into packets that are not for this host but are being routed by the host?

---

**UPDATE:**

1. I'd like to do this in C
2. If it's possible in user space, that's best.  If I need to do this in kernel space, I'd consider it, but might opt to just do pcap instead.

Comment: You want to do this in kernel space or in user space? You want to do this by writing the code or just using some tools?

Answer (score 0):

You have three alternatives to libpcap

- Use packet sockets (AF_PACKET) in user space. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html
- Netfilter also allows you to handle pakcets in user space. http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO.html
- Hack the kernel but I think with the first two options this is not necessary